# ASP.NET MVC Form: Can submit with ENTER key but not Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a simple search form in ASP.NET MVC. Right now my cshtml looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchDemo", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="nameToFind" name="nameToFind">

        <input type="button" id="submitId" name="submit" value="submit" />

    </div>
}
```

And my controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchDemo(string nameToFind)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account"); //Only redirecting for now to test
}
```

Pressing the submit button does not call the controller but pressing ENTER does. I'm guessing that means my click event is getting eaten by JavaScript or something so I tried to pause script execution in Chrome but realized browserlink.js is stuck in an infinite loop. Is that the problem? Either way, how can I stop the infinite loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browser doesn't know to use this button as submit.

Change

```
type="button"
```

To

```
type="submit"
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `<button>Submit(or some other text)</button>` to create a submit button. To prevent submit, add `type="button"` to the button tag (you can technically also add `type="submit"` to a `button`, but there's never really a reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `type` as `"button"`

```
<input type="button" id="submitId" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Change the `type` to `submit`

Answer (score -3):

`<input type="button" id="submitId" name="submit" value="submit" formmethod="post" value="Submit using POST"/>`

You need a formmethod of post in your input.
So that the button knows to post back.
You also need a value attribute. This will be a reference to the Function name within the controller.
[w3 reference](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_formmethod.asp)

Comment: `formmethod` isn't required if the `form` element already has a `method` attribute. This also doesn't fix the `type="button"` which is the real issue.

Comment: Yeah i agree with you. He should change type="submit"